# Android AppWidget Timber not logging

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I'm trying to switch from standard Log to Timber, in order to easily remove logging messages when deploying my app to Google Play, but it is not working

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:3.1.0'
}
```

**MyApp.java**

```
package org.myapp;

...

import timber.log.Timber;
import static timber.log.Timber.DebugTree;

public class MyApp extends AppWidgetProvider {

  @Override
  public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);

    if (MyBuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      Timber.plant(new DebugTree());
    } else {
      //Timber.plant(new CrashReportingTree());
    }

    Timber.d("MyApp.onEnabled");
  }
```

**MyBuildConfig.java**

```
package org.myapp;

public class MyBuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = true;
}
```

The app compiles fine with

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

but when doing

```
adb logcat | grep -i thing
```

my debug statements are not there.

I still would like to see debug messages with the debug apk but not with the release apk, what is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Moving

```
Timber.plant(new DebugTree());
```

to `onUpdate` from `onEnabled` solved the problem, as `onEnabled` was not called since the `AppWidget` was already installed

Comment: I did a mistake by only making it `Timber.plant()`, (which game me no error) instead of the one mentioned in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I believe that happens because `Timber` can't find a Tag in your `AppWidgetProvider`.
Try planting the tree like this:

```
Timber.plant(new DebugTree());
Timber.tag("Your_TAG");
Timber.d("...");
```